# How to show only sleeping processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, grep

How can I display only Sleeping (S) processes from the /proc file? 
I want to only display the processes which are Sleeping using the /proc/status directory.
I tried using egrep but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

To list pid of all processes use:
`ps -eo s,pid`
It shows Process State and their PID's

To filter out only sleeping processes you can use awk:

`ps h -eo s,pid | awk '{ if ($1 == "S") print $2; }'`

Comment: Thank you for answering! Is there any way I can do that with the proc directory?

Comment: @user08: Now it should. The typo was trivial to correct (once you read the [documentation of GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html)....)

Comment: @user08: the standard `ps` utility is implemented on Linux by reading [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a file in /proc/$PID/ called **status**, you can grep it like so

```
status=sleeping

for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; {
    state=$(grep $status $pid/status)
    [[ $state ]] && echo ${pid//'/proc/'/}
}
```

Or using variable substitution

```
pids=( $(grep -l $status /proc/*/status) ); echo ${pids[@]//[!0-9]/}
```

Comment: Just `grep -l sleeping /proc/[0-9]*/status` and maybe pipe it via `| xargs -n1 dirname | xargs -n1 basename` or something like that. Looping and checking return value and `echo` will be very slow. Using `{` `}` instead of `do done` is discouraged - it's a (strange) bash extension, just `do done`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the full filename path, but exactly and only the PID's, try `awk`.

```
$: awk '/sleeping/{ $0=FILENAME; gsub(/[^0-9]/, ""); print $0 }' /proc/[0-9]*/status
```

It's a single, efficient process that runs across all files and outputs only a set of PID's suitable for capture into an array.

Of course, you could also get the full path this way if you wanted that -

```
$: awk '/sleeping/{ print FILENAME }' /proc/[0-9]*/status
```

Or use `sed`

```
$: sed -n '/sleeping/F'  /proc/[0-9]*/status
```

But these basically just do the same thing as [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) suggested with `grep -l sleeping /proc/[0-9]*/status`.

If you just really wanted a reasonably efficient bash-only version, here's a retool of [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12607443/ivan)'s:

```
$: for proc in /proc/[0-9]*/status
   do case "$(<$proc)" in
      *sleeping*) echo "${proc//[^0-9]/}" ;;
      esac
   done
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display only Sleeping (S) processes from the `/proc` file?

Read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Every utility querying about processes go thru `/proc/` (because there is no other way to interact with the kernel to query process state).

However, you should consider using [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html). You want to run:

```
pgrep --runstates S
```

but you might need to compile [procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) from source code (because you need version 3.3.16)